# Selective password generator in C++ and Python

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, security

I have written an **extremely** simple program that has rudimentary password generation with selective character types (symbols, numbers, uppercase, and lowercase). Here is the C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

inline bool getOptions(const std::string & option);
inline long long unsigned getLength();

int main(){
    bool syms   = getOptions("Symbols"),
        nums    = getOptions("Numbers"),
        lower   = getOptions("Lowercase Chars"),
        upper   = getOptions("Uppercase Chars");

    if(!(syms || nums || lower || upper)){
        std::cout << "ERR: No options selected.";
        return -1;
    }

    const std::string str_syms = "`~!@#$%%^&*()-=_+[]{}\\|;:\'\",<.>/\?",
                str_nums = "1234567890",
                str_lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
                str_upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    std::string allowedChars;

    if(syms) allowedChars += str_syms;
    if(nums) allowedChars += str_nums;
    if(lower) allowedChars += str_lower;
    if(upper) allowedChars += str_upper;

    long long unsigned passLength = getLength();

    std::string password;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(long long unsigned i = 0; i < passLength; ++i){
        password += allowedChars[std::rand() % allowedChars.length()];
    }

    std::cout << password << '\n';

    return 0;
}

inline bool getOptions(const std::string & option){
    std::string choice;
    while(true) {

        std::cout << option + " (y/N): ";

        std::getline(std::cin, choice);

        if(tolower(choice[0]) == 'y') {
            return true;
        } else if(tolower(choice[0]) == 'n') {
            return false;
        }

    }
}

inline long long unsigned getLength(){
    std::string str_passLength;
    long long unsigned passLength;
    while(true) {
        std::cout << "Password Length: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, str_passLength);

        try{
            passLength = std::stoll(str_passLength);
        } catch(const std::invalid_argument & e){
            std::cerr << "\n\tERR: Invalid argument.\n";
        } catch(const std::out_of_range & e){
            std::cerr << "\n\tERR: Out of range (long long unsigned).\n";
        } catch(...){
            std::cerr << "\n\tERR: Unknown, something messed up.\n";
        }

        if(passLength > 0){
            return passLength;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I *recreated* the program in Python3, just for practice since I am learning the syntax of Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from random import randint

def getOptions(option):
    choice = ""
    while True:

        print("{} (y/N): ".format(option), end="")
        choice = input()

        if choice[0].lower() == 'y':
            return True
        elif choice[0].lower() == 'n':
            return False

def getLength():
    str_passLength = ""
    passlength = 0
    while True:

        str_passLength = input("Password Length: ")

        try:
            passlength = int(str_passLength)
        except:
            print("\n\tERR: Invalid.\n")

        if passlength > 0:
            return passlength

def main():
    syms    = getOptions("Symbols")
    nums    = getOptions("Numbers")
    lower   = getOptions("Lowercase Chars")
    upper   = getOptions("Uppercase Chars")

    if not(syms or nums or lower or upper):
        print("ERR: No options selected.")
        return -1

    str_syms = "`~!@#$%%^&*()-=_+[]{}\\|;:\'\",<.>/\?"
    str_nums = "1234567890"
    str_lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    str_upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    allowedChars = ""

    if syms: allowedChars += str_syms
    if nums: allowedChars += str_nums
    if lower: allowedChars += str_lower
    if upper: allowedChars += str_upper

    passLength = getLength()

    password = ""

    for i in range(passLength):
        password += allowedChars[randint(0, len(allowedChars) - 1)]

    print(password, '\n')

main()
```

I understand that this program is so short that all *realistically* long password lengths will run almost instantaneously on all modern machines.

However, I wish to improve its readability, logic, and most importantly its brevity. How can I do so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In both languages:

- Why does your `syms` contain `'%'` twice and not contain an escaped `'\\'` at all? (Notice that `'\?'` is equivalent to `'\\?'` in Python, but I would hate to ship code relying on that.)

In Python:

- Look up `argparse` and use it. This will cut down your "option parsing" code to near zero lines. (There's no standard equivalent in C++; but it'll be good if you can adopt similar control flow in C++. Mixing I/O with business logic is never a good thing.)
- `allowedChars[randint(0, len(allowedChars) - 1)]` is a verbose way of saying `random.choice(allowedChars)`.
- At the bottom of your program, you should insert `if __name__ == '__main__':` in front of the call to `main()`, so that you can `import` this module from elsewhere without accidentally calling `main()` in the process.

In C++:

- You repeat the keyword `inline` as if it means something in this context. Don't. Save `inline` for contexts where it actually has a meaningful effect on linkage (as in, where the program wouldn't compile without it).
- Don't declare multiple variables in a single statement; e.g. replace `bool x = a, y = b, z = c;` with `bool x = a; bool y = b; bool z = c;`.
- `std::rand()` is not a blessed way to get random bits in C++. Look up `std::random_device` and `std::uniform_int_distribution`. Admittedly the currently blessed way to get random bits is a bit verbose, but it's probably worth learning at some point.
- Nit: You're missing at least `#include <string>` and `#include <cctype>`.

Comment: Since you are proposing more cryptographically secure approaches in C++, you should suggest to use the [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets) module in Python as well.

Comment: Ah, as far as the double `%` goes, I must've mistakenly used the notation for escaping `%` in C's printf statements. I do believe that I have an escaped `'\\'` in `syms`, it is my understanding that it is right before the `|` character.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I'd suggest is to separate the user interactions and the code logic.  A class for the actual password generation would allow you to only expose those parts that the user would need to access.

Also instead of several string concatenations, it seems to me that setting the maximum size of the string, copying the ones you want then resizing would probably be more efficient.

Here's my take on how it would look:

```
class PasswordChooser
{
    const string symbols = "`~!@#$%^&*()-=_+[]{}|;:\'\",<.>/\?";
    const string numbers = "1234567890";
    const string lowerCase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const string upperCase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    string pool;
    int totalLength = 0;
    bool poolCreated = false;

public:
    PasswordChooser( )
    {
    }

    string CreatePassword(int length,bool duplicates = true )
    {
        if ( !poolCreated )
        {
            return "Create pool first";
        }

        if ( length > pool.size() && !duplicates )
        {
            return "Length is too long.  Create a longer pool or change options";
        }
        string retVal;
        retVal.resize( length );
        for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
        {
            int index = rand() % pool.size();
            retVal[i] = pool[index];
            if ( !duplicates )
            {
                pool.erase( pool.begin() + index);
            }
        }

        poolCreated = false;
        return retVal;
    }
    void CreatePool( bool hasSymbols = false , bool hasNumbers = false , bool hasLowerCase = false , bool hasUpperCase = false )
    {
        pool = string( symbols.length() + numbers.length() + lowerCase.length() + upperCase.length(),'\0' );
        totalLength = 0;
        if ( hasSymbols )
        {
            copy( symbols.begin() , symbols.end() , pool.begin() + totalLength );
            totalLength += symbols.length();
        }
        if ( hasNumbers )
        {
            copy( numbers.begin() , numbers.end() , pool.begin() + totalLength );
            totalLength += numbers.length();
        }
        if ( hasLowerCase )
        {
            copy( lowerCase.begin() , lowerCase.end() , pool.begin() + totalLength );
            totalLength += lowerCase.length();
        }
        if ( hasUpperCase )
        {
            copy( upperCase.begin() , upperCase.end() , pool.begin() + totalLength );
            totalLength += upperCase.length();
        }
        pool.resize( totalLength );
        if ( pool.size() == 0 )
        {
            poolCreated = false;
        }
        else
        {
            poolCreated = true;
            random_shuffle( pool.begin() , pool.end() );
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I would make the logic in your Python main function slightly shorter by using what @Quuxplusone already suggested in [his answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/161567/98493). But I would go further and make a `get_password` function that takes the requested length and the allowed characters as arguments. It uses [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice). It also uses `_` as name for an unused loop variable, [as is customary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5477153/4042267).

In addition, I implemented the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) you would need, including the validation step that at least one charset should be used.

I made the charset a `list`, because extending lists is slightly faster than string addition, even though it probably won't matter in this small case.

Python also has a built-in [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) module that pre-defines a lot of commonly used character classes (and it has all of the ones you use).

I also renamed your variables according to Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

```
import argparse
import random
import string


def parse_args(args=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("n", type=int, default=8, help="Length of password")
    parser.add_argument("--syms", action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument("--nums", action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument("--lower", action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument("--upper", action='store_true')

    args = parser.parse_args(args)
    if not (args.syms or args.nums or args.lower or args.upper):
        parser.error('No character options selected')

    return args


def get_password(n, allowed_chars):
    return "".join(random.choice(allowed_chars) for _ in range(n))


def main():
    # use argparse module to get arguments
    args = parse_args()

    allowed_chars = []
    if args.syms:
        allowed_chars.extend(string.punctuation)
    if args.nums:
        allowed_chars.extend(string.digits)
    if args.lower:
        allowed_chars.extend(string.ascii_lowercase)
    if args.upper:
        allowed_chars.extend(string.ascii_uppercase)

    # Use a password generating function
    print(get_password(args.n, allowed_chars))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Side note: I made the `parse_args` function accept an argument `args`, so I can easily test it. By default `argparse` tries to parse `sys.argv`, but if `args` is not `None`, it will take a list of strings. So you can test it with e.g. `args = parse_args(["6", '--lower', '--upper'])`.